# Using a block statement to encapsulate data in TypeScript

Tags: tsconfig, tsc

I'm testing out variable scopes in blocks and I'm just following along the official MDN docs and when I run this following snippet I get a different output then what's expected.

`const` variable radius is defined inside a `block` and when accessed outside of that block it should be undefined, but its not so, and I get the number 10 printed out. I'm transpiling this from Typescript and using nodemon.

```
let sector;
{
  // These variables are scoped to this block and are not
  // accessible after the block
  const angle = Math.PI / 3;
  const radius = 10;
  sector = {
    radius,
    angle,
    area: (angle / 2) * radius ** 2,
    perimeter: 2 * radius + angle * radius,
  };
}
console.log(sector);
// {
//   radius: 10,
//   angle: 1.0471975511965976,
//   area: 52.35987755982988,
//   perimeter: 30.471975511965976
// }
console.log(typeof radius, radius); // "undefined" "undefined"
```

output:

```
   {
      radius: 10,
      angle: 1.0471975511965976,
      area: 52.35987755982988,
      perimeter: 30.471975511965976
    }
    number 10
```

what would be the explanation for this?

**Edit:**

like @Dimava said the transpiled JS has var instead of const and that's the reason `radius` is in scope.
the question now is even though in my tsconfig.json i have `target` set to `ESnext` we still have `var` instead of `const`

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

after i run `tsc .\fileName.ts`
this is the transpiled js

```
var sector;
{
    // These variables are scoped to this block and are not
    // accessible after the block
    var angle = Math.PI / 3;
    var radius = 145;
    sector = {
        radius: radius,
        angle: angle,
        area: (angle / 2) * Math.pow(radius, 2),
        perimeter: 2 * radius + angle * radius,
    };
}
console.log(sector);
// {
//   radius: 10,
//   angle: 1.0471975511965976,
//   area: 52.35987755982988,
//   perimeter: 30.471975511965976
// }
console.log(typeof radius, radius); // "undefined" "undefined"
```

and his other solution which is using `tsx` works well and as expected. unfortunately i would need to get tsc working

Comment: I recommend trying https://github.com/esbuild-kit/tsx for running TS code as is instead ( as `tsx file.ts` or `tsx watch file.ts` )

Comment: "*I'm transpiling this from Typescript*" - how exactly are you doing that? Please show us the command and the transpiler config, and have a look at the transpiled code.

Comment: @Bergi ive added added more info to the question like you asked

Comment: @some_groceries try running just `tsc`, will that help?

Comment: it may be ignoring the project as you run it on file input with no --project flag I dunno

Comment: @Dimava yep that worked.  i'l accept your answer,  please do add in this extra bit of info later. thanks a lot :)  works with just `tsc` and also with `tsc --project .\tsconfig.json` i want to know how you came to this conclusion and what was your thought process?

Comment: @some_groceries why do you need the `nodemon`? There's `tsc --watch`

Comment: @Dimava i'l certainly need nodemon to run the .JS files. tsc --watch would only transpile the files and not run JS. if i had used tsx as you suggested i wouldn't need nodemon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running `tsc <file>`, and that ignores the project's `tsconfig.json` unless you explicitly use the `--project` flag.

Run just `tsc` and then it'll work fine.

---

If your `target` is ES5 or below it transpiles as

```
"use strict";
var sector;
{
    // These variables are scoped to this block and are not
    // accessible after the block
    var angle = Math.PI / 3;
    var radius = 10;
    sector = {
        radius: radius,
        angle: angle,
        area: (angle / 2) * Math.pow(radius, 2),
        perimeter: 2 * radius + angle * radius,
    };
}
console.log(sector);
// {
//   radius: 10,
//   angle: 1.0471975511965976,
//   area: 52.35987755982988,
//   perimeter: 30.471975511965976
// }
console.log(typeof radius, radius); // "undefined" "undefined"
```

leaking `var`iables to outer scope

Check your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: you are right but i do have `"target": "ES2017"` in my tsconfig.json